# Reducing cyclomatic complexity of object oriented python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, cyclomatic-complexity

I am trying to reduce cylomatic complexity of code, because according to [pylama](https://github.com/klen/pylama) my definition is 'too complex' and suggested [solution](https://lintlyci.github.io/Flake8Rules/rules/C901.html) includes calling functions with dictionary mappings.

So I tried it on my object oriented code but failed miserably.

```
class trial:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'
        self.b = 'b'

    def a(self):
        return self.a

    def b(self):
        return self.b

    def select_one(self, option):
        map_func = {
        1 : self.a,
        2 : self.b
        }
        return map_func[option]()

t = trial()
print(t.select_one(1))
```

If this is not possible what are the other possible solutions to reduce cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: you should define `map_func` once and for all in `__init__` so it's not redone each time, else what's the point of a dictionary

Comment: besides that I see no complexity...

Comment: also you have functions and strings called the same. Please change that. This is probably why it doesn't work for you

Comment: Why would it reduce cyclomatic complexity? You introduce a factory function that calls one of two other funcs that you could have called by name yourself? Also: use `dict.get()` or die horribly on "alosdfböoads" given to your mapper. This is almost code obfuscation - who knows what 1 or 2 might do?

Comment: @PatrickArtner That was just for example I will change my options from 1,2 to something more sensible, my previous (too complex code had) a single method with if else ladder for choosing an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, the dictionary should be defined in `__init__` or you have `O(n)` complexity each time you enter your `select_one` function (dictionary is built each time, which makes the example in your link wrong)

second, your methods have the same name as your attributes. Change that:

```
class trial:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'
        self.b = 'b'
        self.map_func = {
        1 : self.f_a,
        2 : self.f_b
        }

    def f_a(self):
        return self.a

    def f_b(self):
        return self.b

    def select_one(self, option):
        return self.map_func[option]()

t = trial()
print(t.select_one(1))
```

Comment: Your code throws error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "function_call_dict.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(t.select_one(1))
    return map_func[option]()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: weird, as I tested it as is. Are you sure you copied exactly?